# How to calculate total no of pixel of an object from image captured by camera?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, image

I have an object of one color and I need to calculate the exact no of pixel occupied by object in captured image. How can I do this? I want to do this in Opencv. Please help...

Answer (score 2):

There are inbuilt functions for that in OpenCV.

1) Threshold the image so that object you needed is white and all other things are black.

Since you already have the object, i think you have done this step. If not, use [Threshold functions](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold) in opencv

2) Find contours in the image

Use [FindContours function](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) for this.

3) Now find the area of the contour of the object you needed, which is the number of pixels occupied by it.

Use [ContourArea function](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#contourarea) for this

**Additional :**

Not only just an area, there are a lot of other things you can find about an object like perimeter, centroid, mean value, orientation etc. [Check this article to see them](http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2012/04/contour-features.html). Code is in Python, but you won't find any difficult to understand it.